# Selecting the correct item using material's GridList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mobx

I have a react-mobx code that's working with Material-UI and looks something like this:

```
render() {
  // some consts declarations

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={selectedPhoto} alt={'image title'} />
      <GridList className={classes.gridList} cols={2.5}>
        {photos.map(tile => (
          <GridListTile key={tile} onClick={this.selectPhoto}>
            <img src={tile} alt={'image title'} />
            <GridListTileBar
              classes={{
                root: classes.titleBar,
                title: classes.title
              }}
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This shows a list of photos. I would like to change the selected photo when the user clicks one of the GridListTile. The key (`tile`) is actually an image url.

As seen in the code, I tried adding `onClick={this.selectPhoto}` when the `selectPhoto` function looks like this:

```
selectPhoto = (photo) => {
  this.props.rootStore.selectPhoto(photo);
}
```

The argument `photo` that is sent to the function is not `tile` (the image url) as I would like to have. How can I pass this argument to the function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an inline arrow function and pass along your `tile` to `selectPhoto`:

```
photos.map(tile => (
  <GridListTile key={tile} onClick={() => this.selectPhoto(tile)}>
    <img src={tile} alt={'image title'} />
    <GridListTileBar
      classes={{
        root: classes.titleBar,
        title: classes.title
      }}
    />
  </GridListTile>
))
```